# call a function that exist in java script when click on RadButton Telerik

Tags: javascript, button, click

How to call a function that exist in java script when click on RadButton Telerik?I use this code but it does not work

```
  <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButtonClear" runat="server" Height="40px" Text="Clear" 
                OnClientClicked="x();">
            </telerik:RadButton>

    <input name="text" id="idname"/>
```

javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  language="JavaScript" >
     function x(button, args)
           {
              document.getElementById('idname').value = "1";
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButtonClear" runat="server" Height="40px" Text="Clear" 
                OnClientClicked="x">
            </telerik:RadButton>

<input name="text" id="idname"/>
```

Try This......